# Class.forName(name, instantiation, classLoader) doesn't add class to classpath

Tags: java, classloader, dynamic-class-loaders

I'm generating `.java` class files at the runtime and need to utilize those classes inside the code instantly.
So I compile the `.java` classes using Compiler API to make `.class` files:

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<>();

StandardJavaFileManager manager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);

File file = new File("path to file");

Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> sources = manager.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(Arrays.asList(file));

CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, manager, diagnostics, null, null, sources);

task.call();

manager.close();
```

Then I need to get references to those compiled classes using `Class.forName()`, But if I just call `Class.forName("com.foo.Bar")` it throws `ClassNotFoundException`, Assuming it's because the new `.class` files aren't added to `classpath` I looked for the methods of adding classes to the `classpath` at runtime. I encountered some ambiguities related to this concept:

**1.** Is this approach (of compiling the `.java` file first, using compiler API, and add it to class loader at the second step) correct? To be able utilizing the class in the code instantly.

**2.** AFAIK, There are 2 methods to dynamically load classes into classpath at runtime: one is using a custom ClassLoader like this: (which I had error to compile as it complained that `BuiltinClassLoader` doesn't have `addURL` method):

```
    // Get the ClassLoader class
    ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    Class<?> clazz = cl.getClass();

    // Get the protected addURL method from the parent URLClassLoader class
    Method method = clazz.getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[] { URL.class });

    // Run projected addURL method to add JAR to classpath
    method.setAccessible(true);
    method.invoke(cl, new Object[] { cls });
```

Another method is using `Class.forName(name, instantiation, classLoader)` to add a class to the classpath (which gives the class reference at the same too). The first method I wasn't able to apply since I got a compiler error (Java 11) as mentioned above.
Regarding the second method, Would `Class.forName(name, instantiation, classLoader)` attach the new classes to the `classpath` if we call the default class loader like this? :

```
Class.forName("com.foo.Bar",true, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
// or:
Class.forName("com.foo.Bar",true, ApiHandler.class.getClassLoader());
```

It doesn't work for me. Which variation of the above classLoader arguments 
are correct and why do these don't work? Is it mandotary to create a custom classloader and pass it to the `Class.forName()`?

**3.** I'm making the `.java` files inside the `com.foo` package in `src` folder of the eclipse project. Their compiled `.class` files are also generated at the same folder (using compiler API). When I refresh project using eclipse (right-click on the project -> Refresh) the related `.class` files would be generated in the `target/classes` folder and that's when the classes could be accessed through the code (e.g using `Class.forName("com.foo.Bar)`. May it be that if I produce `.class` files (by compiler API) in the `target/classes` folder, The classes would be recognizable without the need of introducing them to the classpath?

---

**UPDATE:**

I was able to use the compiled classes in my code, By saving the respected `.class` files in the `target/classes` folder, mentioned in the 3rd question above) of the project. (By adding `-d` option to the compiler's `getTask()` method:

```
Iterable<String> options = Arrays.asList( new String[] { "-d", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/target/classes/"} );
.
.
.

CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, manager, diagnostics, options, null, sources);
```

**This way, It seems the classes are not even required to be added to the classpath using classLoader**; as the class is accessible using a simple `Class.forName()`. **How Do you explain this?**

```
Class<?> cls1 = Class.forName("com.foo.Bar");
```

And also with through the ClassLoader way, of course:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(); 

Class<?> cls = classLoader.loadClass("com.foo.Bar");
```

Comment: URIClassLoader?

Comment: @dan1st If you mean the code snippet to make custom classLoader, I got the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60766/190929), Here's also a representation of utilizing `URLClassLoader` to make a custom ClassLoader:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1011126/190929

Comment: I thought it could help you.

Comment: @dan1st Thanks, I have no Idea how to use it differently than what's brought in the above link in my previous comment.

Comment: You can create an URLClassLoader with a Constructor(with an URL). With that you can use `loadClass(String)`

Comment: Your code snippet following “*one is using a custom ClassLoader*” is *not* using a custom class loader but trying to hack into the system class loader. Using a custom class loader is what @dan1st suggested, creating a new `URLClassLoader` and call `loadClass` on it or use `Class.forName("com.foo.Bar", irrelevant, theNewlyCreatedLoader)`. When you tell the compiler to write into a directory in your class path, the class may become available, but only if a) no previous attempt to load it has been made and a) there is a directory on the class path (instead of jar files or module storages).

Answer (score 1):

The safest solution is to create a new `ClassLoader` implementation and load the generated classes via the new loader, like shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48888184/2711488).

But since Java 9, there is the possibility to define classes within your own context, i.e. within the same package, if no class with that name has been defined/loaded yet. Such a class definition may even supersede an definition on the class path, as said, as long as it has not been loaded yet. So not only subsequent `Class.forName(String)` calls will get resolved to this class definition but even non-reflective references.

This can be demonstrated with the following program.

```
class Dummy { // to make the compiler happy
    static native void extensionMethod();
}
public class CompileExtension {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, IllegalAccessException {
        // customize these, if you want, null triggers default behavior
        DiagnosticListener<JavaFileObject> diagnosticListener = null;
        Locale locale = null;

        // the actual class implementation, to be present at runtime only
        String class1 =
            "class Dummy {\n"
          + "    static void extensionMethod() {\n"
          + "        System.out.println(\"hello from dynamically compiled code\");\n"
          + "    }\n"
          + "}";
        JavaCompiler c = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        StandardJavaFileManager fm
          = c.getStandardFileManager(diagnosticListener, locale, Charset.defaultCharset());
        // define where to store compiled class files - use a temporary directory
        fm.setLocation(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT,
            Set.of(Files.createTempDirectory("compile-test").toFile()));
        JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = c.getTask(null, fm,
            diagnosticListener, Set.of(), Set.of(),
            Set.of(new SimpleJavaFileObject(
                URI.create("string:///Class1.java"), JavaFileObject.Kind.SOURCE) {
                    public CharSequence getCharContent(boolean ignoreEncodingErrors) {
                        return class1;
                    }
                }));

        if(task.call()) {
            FileObject fo = fm.getJavaFileForInput(
                StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, "Dummy", JavaFileObject.Kind.CLASS);
            // these are the class bytes of the first class
            byte[] classBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fo.toUri()));
            MethodHandles.lookup().defineClass(classBytes);

            Dummy.extensionMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

The `Dummy` definition only exists to be able to insert an invocation to the desired method at compile-time, whereas at runtime, the dynamically defined class takes its place, before the method gets invoked.

But handle with care. As said, the custom class loader is the safest solution. Normally, you should create compile-time references to extensions via an interface which is always present and only load implementations dynamically, which can be cast to the interface at runtime and then used through the API defined by the interface.